# How do I restore a site using drush?

Tags: drush

I have been learning drush and I loving it. i am having a tough time understanding how to backup and restore my site. Often I bork my site and just need to quickly restore it. These are the steps I am following and I am met with the following error:

```
Destination directory /Users/Nigel/Sites/sitename/ already exists.      [error]

Unable to restore files to /Users/Nigel/Sites/sitename/
```

1. cd to my Drupal installation.
2. Create a Drush archive dump (code and db in one)

   drush ard
3. Grab my backup (e.g. sitename.20130221_055426.tar.gz) and place it
   back into the root of my Drupal installation

   drush arr sitename.20130221_055426.tar.gz

There is a similar question [How do I use Drush correctly to restore a site via the arr command?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54974/how-do-i-use-drush-correctly-to-restore-a-site-via-the-arr-command) , however the issue and thus the answer has to do with different db credentials, rather than the steps to restore a site.

I am obviously doing something completely wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding --overwrite to your restore command, that will let you overwrite an existing site.